# Callback Issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf, callback

I am trying to execute a *WCF* service call, from function `one()`. Only once this is complete I want function `two()` to be executed. The issue I have is that function `two()` is invoked before function `one()` completes execution and the WCF service returns the result. How can I solve this please? I am using callback function, so I can't figure out why, given that the response does not exceed 3 seconds.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var jsonGetFileResult = "";

    function one(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            //var jsonGetFileResult = "";
            console.log('01: into one');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ‘http: //wcf.google.com’, //this is the wcf call
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function(data) {
                    jsonGetFileResult = stringifyNewsletter(data);
                    console.log('03: ' + jsonGetFileResult);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
            callback();
        }, 3000);
    }

    function stringifyNewsletter(data) {
        var removeHeader = JSON.stringify(data);
        var file = removeHeader.split('"');
        console.log('02: ' + file[3]);
        return file[3];
    }

    function two(linkToNewsletter) {
        window.open(linkToNewsletter, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        return false;
    }

    /* now we make use of the callback */
    one(function() {
        alert(jsonGetFileResult);
        // "one" triggers "two" as soon as it is done, note how "two" is a parameter
        two(jsonGetFileResult);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking the callback *outside* of the ajax "success" function. The `$.ajax()` call is **asynchronous** — the call will return to your code essentially immediately, after launching the HTTP request and without waiting for it to finish.

If you move the line

```
    callback();
```

to *inside* the "success" handler, then that will run *after* the HTTP request completes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put callback inside success function like that:

```
 function one(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //var jsonGetFileResult = "";
        console.log('01: into one');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: ‘http: //wcf.google.com’, //this is the wcf call
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(data) {
                jsonGetFileResult = stringifyNewsletter(data);
                console.log('03: ' + jsonGetFileResult);
                callback();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    }, 3000);
}
```